# Giving interactive control of a Python program to the user

Tags: python, python-3.x, pwntools

I need my Python program to do some stuff, and at a certain point give control to the user (like a normal Python shell when you run `python3` or whatever) so that he can interact with it via command line. I was thinking of using `pwntools`'s `interactive()` method but I' m not sure how I would use that for the local program instead of a remote.

How would I do that?

Any idea is accepted, if `pwntools` is not needed, even better.

Answer (score 1):

Use IPython

If you haven't already, add the package IPython using pip, anaconda, etc.

Add to your code:

`from IPython import embed`

Then where you want a "breakpoint", add:

`embed()`

I find this mode, even while coding to be very efficient.